# OpenXML Merge Word Documents Formatting of multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have multiple template docx files which I am trying to merge together. If the first file is formatted as two columns, when I merge the files it automatically sets the next files as multiple column word document and changes the formatting even if it was a one column file previously before the merge. However, when i select the normal docx file with no multiple columns first, it tries to set all the multiple column text into a single column and changes the formatting.

I am trying to merge these documents without any formatting changing. Heres my code so far:

```
 private void MergeDocuments()
{

    bool docfilechecked = keepworddoc.Checked;
    string caseno = casetextboxinput.Value;
    string nameno = patentee;

    string[] mergeFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryrootmerge + caseno + @"\", sequenceCounter + "*.doc*")
       .Select(Path.GetFullPath)
       .ToArray();

    string filename = caseno + @" - " + nameno + " - PoA Form.docx";
    string directory = directoryrootmerge + caseno;
    string outputFileName = directoryrootmerge + caseno + @"\" + caseno + @" - " + nameno + " - PoA Form.docx";
    //string outputFileName2 = directoryrootmerge + caseno + @"\" + caseno + @" - " + nameno + "- PoA Form.pdf";


    if (mergeFiles.Length == 1)
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(mergeFiles[0], outputFileName, true);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < mergeFiles.Length; i++)
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mergeFiles[0], true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + i;

                //Append page break
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(new Run((new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
                mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(para, mainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);

                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(mergeFiles[i], FileMode.Open))
                {
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                 }

                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                //new page, if you like it...
                //mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
                mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
                mainPart.Document.Save();
                myDoc.Close();
                System.IO.File.Copy(mergeFiles[0], outputFileName, true);

            }
    }
}
```

I have added a page break after each file to see if that resets the formatting on merge but doesnt seem to work - can anyone see where i might be going wrong?

Comment: I have done some research and it saying to use a property of alt chunk called match source, but not sure how to use it - can someone help?

Comment: MatchSource matchSrc = new MatchSource();
matchSrc.Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.BooleanValues.True;
altChunk.AppendChild(matchSrc);

Comment: The type or namespace name 'BooleanValues' does not exist in the namespace 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the OpenXML PowerTools? They contain code to combine OpenXML documents...

[DocumentBuilder of PowerTools](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/documentbuilder-developer-center/)